# Updating Access 2002 in WINE?

Tags: updates, microsoft-access, wine

I am looking at running Access 2002 for our company inside of WINE so we can start to break away from our older Window 2000 / XP systems and make a move to Ubuntu.

The only problem I am running into is how to update Access. In order for our database applet to work right we have install Access 2002 SP3 and all of the updates. (Not sure what update exactly I just know we usually install all of them)

Is there a way I can run Windows update inside WINE, I am gonna guess I have a snowballs chance in hell making that work. Am I wrong?

If so what is the other alternative to getting all of the updates, since Access 2002 is no longer being updated I only have to get the updates once.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps download the stand-alone redistributable version of the [Office 2002/XP SP3](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23334) from Microsoft, and run it manually?

Comment: That was what I was thinking. Is there a place I can find a list of all the updates?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/search.aspx?q=access+2002 :)